# Dynos count in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, scale

Is it possible to get the total number of dynos through heroku CLI? I mean I'm trying to do something very simple: while some-condition heroku ps:scale worker+1, but I want to establish some maxWorkerNumber, so it isn't like scaling forever... but I don't know how can I get the actual worker count

I'm working with python and I'm trying to auto-scale workers based in a queue size, but for what I have seen there is no add-on that let me do this, that's why I'm trying scale directly with the CLI. If someone can help me I'll be eternally grateful

Answer (score 1):

Just use `heroku ps`

```
> heroku help ps
Usage: heroku ps

 list dynos for an app

Example:

 $ heroku ps
 === run: one-off dyno
 run.1: up for 5m: `bash`

 === web: `bundle exec thin start -p $PORT`
 web.1: created for 30s

Additional commands, type "heroku help COMMAND" for more details:

  ps:resize DYNO1=1X|2X [DYNO2=1X|2X ...]     #  resize dynos to the given size
  ps:restart [DYNO]                           #  restart an app dyno
  ps:scale DYNO1=AMOUNT1 [DYNO2=AMOUNT2 ...]  #  scale dynos by the given amount
  ps:stop DYNOS                               #  stop an app dyno
```

If you don't want to use the command line, the API can also be used to mange dynos: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno